# How to ensure unique broker IDs in a docker kafka service

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-swarm

I want to create a scalable kafka cluster, but each kafka instance needs a unique broker ID. What is a good way to ensure this?

Below you can find the compose file I am using to deploy my application. I am using `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml mystack` to deploy it to my docker swarm. Currently the broker ID is set to 1, but this will not work when I increase the number of kafka instances from one to two with e.g. `docker service scale <KAFKA-SERVICE-ID>=2`, and that is the problem that I am trying to solve.

```
---
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 22181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: localhost:22888:23888
    network_mode: host
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    network_mode: host
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:22181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:19092
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"
```

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that by default, if you don't assign kafka a broker ID, zookeeper will automatically assign kafka a unique broker ID. So you can safely scale a kafka service up or down without concerning yourself at all with management of broker IDs. See http://kafka.apache.org/090/documentation.html for more info (search "zookeeper sequence starts from MaxReservedBrokerId + 1" for the relevant row in the table). By default, MaxReservedBrokerId is 1000, so your first auto-assigned broker ID will be 1001, and as you add additional kafka containers, zookeeper will allocate sequentially. So your second kafka container will have broker ID of 1002, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well to Answer your question .. did you try to use an environment variable... like this

```
version: '3'
services:
     zookeeper:
        image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
        environment:
          ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
          ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 22181
          ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
          ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
          ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
          ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: localhost:22888:23888
        network_mode: host
        extra_hosts:
          - "moby:127.0.0.1"
      kafka:
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
        network_mode: host
        depends_on:
          - zookeeper
        environment:
          KAFKA_BROKER_ID: ${TAG}
          KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:22181
          KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:19092
        extra_hosts:
          - "moby:127.0.0.1"
```

Pay attention to the substitution done against the KAFKA_BROKER_ID , you might also run into the issue of ports if the service is scaled on the same node but that is a different problem to solve.

So before scaling up just change the value of the variable to some different value , you may want to script this out as well.

More info on this can be found here https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file

Once the service starts you can see the broker id in the console log

```
kafka_1      | KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:19092
zookeeper_1  | ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT=2
kafka_1      | KAFKA_BROKER_ID=9
zookeeper_1  | ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME=2000
kafka_1      | KAFKA_VERSION=1.0.0
kafka_1      | KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:22181
zookeeper_1  | ZULU_OPENJDK_VERSION=8=8.17.0.3
kafka_1      | LANG=C.UTF-8
zookeeper_1  | _=/usr/bin/env
```